# What is difference between @MicronautTest and EmbeddedServer

Tags: micronaut

What is difference between starting a server using `MicronautTest` and `EmbeddedServer` while using them in Unit/Integration testing in `Micronaut` framework.

Option A:

```java
@MicronautTest
public class Test{

    @Inject
    EmbeddedServer server;
}
```

Option B:

```java
EmbeddedServer embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class);
```

Comment: Hey @krutesh since you are a new Stackoverflow user here is a friendly reminder. Please have a look at the answers below and accept one of them if it was helpful to you. Thank you

Comment: Option B can be used to have a context per test. That is sometimes useful to test the same thing with different configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between option A and B is the Micronaut version you use.

**Option B** was used in early stages of Micronaut 1.0 when the [module `micronaut-test`](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html) was not available yet. So option B is writing integration tests without the support of `micronaut-test`.

```java
EmbeddedServer embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class);
```

After a while (between Micronaut 1.0.1 and 1.0.4) OCI introduced **option A** the module `micronaut-test` that make testing life a lot easier. It allows you to write Spring Boot alike test

```java
@MicronautTest
public class Test extends Specification {

    @Inject
    EmbeddedServer server
}
```

I recommend to only use option A since it is the preferred way of testing and it provides you the possibility to use `@Inject` of any Micronaut bean without have to work directly with the Micronaut application context. When writing tests with the Spock framework it furthermore it allows you to replace Micronaut beans with mocks on the fly like this example shows:

```java
@MicronautTest
class MathMockServiceSpec extends Specification {

    @Inject
    MathService mathService 

    @Unroll
    void "should compute #num to #square"() {
        when:
        def result = mathService.compute(num)

        then:
        1 * mathService.compute(num) >> Math.pow(num, 2)  
        result == square

        where:
        num | square
        2   | 4
        3   | 9
    }

    @MockBean(MathServiceImpl) 
    MathService mathService() {
        Mock(MathService) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class)` will start the server (in a test or otherwise).  `@MicronautTest` can be applied to a test and the result of that is that the server will be started and in addition to that, the test will be subjected to dependency injection.  In general I would suggest `@MicronautTest`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@MicronautTest
```

provides way to inject dependencies such as (in kotlin)

```
class MyTest(
@Client("/") client:HttpClient
@Inject val dataSource:DataSource){
// some tests
}
```

instead of manually creating them it is recommended to use MicronautTest